# how to make generic sql query in java?

Tags: java, sql

I have tried this but I couldn't get column name from this query.

```
insert into table2(select 'empno', empno from table11 )
```

I write this query but I get expected result like:

```
-------------------------------------------------
col1     |    col2
------------------------------------------------------- 
empno        101
empno        102
empno        103
empno        104
empno        105
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

but the problem is I want give  col_name 'empno' in dynamic way. How is that possible?

Comment: Can you please clarify your requirement a little more?

Comment: i want to give empno from outside of the query  how it is possible?that is my question?

Comment: @dumbuu How exactly do you want to give the name "in a dynamic way"? What exactly are you trying to do? Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query on how to ask SQL related questions.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

if I got your question correctly, please try below

```
insert into table2 select 'empno' empno from table11
```